# Правильно ли составлены схемы двух этих предложений?

Tags: синтаксис, сложное-предложение

1. Они знали: где-то совсем рядом должна быть тропа, но из-за снежной пыли ничего не было видно. **[ ]:( ),( ).**
2. Потом лежали во тьме сотрясающегося от порывов ветра брезента и вслушивались в тоскливую жуть пурги, и никто не знал, когда она кончится. **[ ],( ), ( ).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *Они знали: где-то совсем рядом должна быть тропа, но из-за снежной пыли ничего не было видно.*

Сложноподчинённая (бессоюзная) часть предложения соединена с последним предложением сочинительной связью (союзом *но*). Схема:  [  ]: (  ), но [  ].

2. *Потом лежали во тьме сотрясающегося от порывов ветра брезента и вслушивались в тоскливую жуть пурги, и никто не знал, когда она кончится.*

Между первым и вторым предложениями связь сочинительная, они равноправны (от первого нельзя задать вопрос ко второму). Схема:  [  ], и [  ], (  ).